# Printing out dictionary without whitespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing some exercises but I am not able to complete due to some formatting I am supposed to follow when printing the dictionary.

```
a_dict = {
          'apple': 1,
          'orange': 2
          }
```

Output

```
{'apple': 1, 'orange': 2}
```

Is there any way I can format it to be like this?

```
{ 'apple':1, 'orange':2 }
```

Basically edit the spaces in between the output.

Comment: You can always print the keys and the values any way you like/need. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify the `__repr__` method of built-ins such as `dict` but you can print it as you wish. For example:

```py
>>> a = {'apple': 1, 'orange': 2}
>>> print("{{ {} }}".format(", ".join(f"{repr(k)}:{repr(v)}" for k, v in a.items())))
{ 'apple':1, 'orange':2 }
```